# How to redirect with params in JSF2?

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2

When I enter the page I want to rediect to another page with params (f:viewParam). How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `includeViewParams=true` parameter to the outcome. JSF will then include the view params.

---

**Update** as per the comments you seem to want to change the request/response inside the view side. This is not guaranteed to work. The view is part of the response. Once the response is committed, there is a point of **no return**. You cannot change the request/response to another destination.

You want to handle this in the controller instead. If those requests originate from a JSF action, then you should do the controlling job *there*. Just let it return the desired outcome. Or if those requests originate from external links/bookmarks/etc, then you should do the controlling job in a `Filter` class.

Comment: Wait, you want to redirect when the view is included/rendered instead of when an action is invoked? Why? What's the functional requirement?

Comment: But **why** in the view? What's the functional requirement? Where do those requests come from? Why are you controlling this in the view instead of in a controller?

Comment: I mean, are those requests coming from JSF actions or from bookmarks/links/direct? If from JSF actions, it should be done *there*. If from bookmarks/etc, you should create a `Filter` to control this. Anyway, I updated the answer.